# Cannot telnet or SSH to the ec2 instance after changing the Instance type of it

Tags: amazon-ec2, root, volumes, instancetype

When the instance type is changed , some nodes give this issue  "cannot telnet or ssh", and after  reverting to the previous Instance type again can telnet and ssh.
This issue is mostly coming with the nodes with a magnetic volume as the root volume where the device name is `xvd`, no issues encounter with nodes having ssd volume as the root volume and device name is in `nvme` . What can be the reason and how to resolve this?
Note : I am trying to change this from `m4.large` to `m5.large`

Comment: Please use `ssh -vvv` and edit your question to include the _exact_ error message(s) you are receiving. It is quite likely that the instance received a different **Public IP address** after it was stopped and started, so make sure that you are connecting to the correct IP address by looking at the instance in the EC2 console and checking the Public IP address displayed.

Comment: These nodes are private instances and have no public  IP.

Comment: Okay, please use `ssh -vvv` and add the output to your question.

Comment: It gives a connections refused log , even when I telnet to the port  it gives connection refused, but after reverting to the previous instance type I can telnet .

Answer (score 1):

You are upgrading from the M4 family to the M5 family.

I notice that the description says: *"Requires HVM AMIs that include drivers for ENA and NVMe"*

Therefore, you should run it as an M4, install the ENA drivers, and only then change to an M5.

See: [Enabling enhanced networking with the Elastic Network Adapter (ENA) on Linux instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html)